# Using "OR" in a JOIN Clause to build a Grouped Rank for a huge dataset

Tags: sql, join

I am new here and as well as to SQL.  I am trying build a query that will result in the Rank Column.  However, I have a huge data set and I need this to be done using a JOIN Function.

```
SalesPerson Dept  Customers Rank
----------- ----- --------- ----
Bill        DeptA     20      1
Ted         DeptA     20      2
Jane        DeptA     40      3
Bill        DeptB     50      1
Mary        DeptB     60      2
```

This is what I have written so far, but it isn't working.  Anyone can help?

```
SELECT tbl1.SalesPerson ,
       tbl1.Dept ,
       tbl1.Customers ,
       Count(*) AS Rank
FROM       tbl AS tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl AS tbl2 ON ( (           tbl2.Dept        = tbl1.Dept 
                              AND (     tbl2.Customers   = tbl1.Customers
                                    AND tbl2.SalesPerson < tbl1.SalesPerson
                                  )
                            ) 
                            OR
                            (     tbl2.Dept      = tbl1.Dept
                              AND tbl2.Customers < tbl1.Customers
                            )
                          )
GROUP BY tbl1.SalesPerson ,
         tbl1.Dept ,
         tbl1.Customers;
```

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your question with the specific database.

Comment: I edited the SQL to organize it with indents.  How do we know if what you have written is semantically equivalent to your business question ? i.e.,  please describe what you want the query to do, in English...

Comment: OR in a join is rarely a good performance element, so you're likely better of by using UNION logic.
That's usually also more easy to understand as time goes by and code ages. So use a union to subselect and join that into the remainder logic.

Comment: Thanks for all of the quick replies.  I am using MS Access.  What I a trying to do is to rank by department the number of current customers by Sales Person.  If there is a tie I want it broken by a Sales person's Name.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support window/analytic functions.  So, the easiest way to get what you want is:

```
select t.SalesPerson, t.Dept, t.Customers,
       row_number() over (partition by t.Dept order by t.Customers) as rank
from tbl t;
```

Some "databases" such as MS Access do not support this function.  I would approach this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.SalesPerson, t.Dept, t.Customers,
       (select count(*)
        from tbl t2
        where t2.Dept = t.Dept and
              (t.Customers < t2.Customers or
               t.Customers = t2.Customers and t.SalesPerson <= t.SalesPerson
              )
       ) as rank
from tbl t;
```

EDIT:

To improve performance of this query, create an index on `tbl(Dept, Customers, SalesPerson)`.

Comment: I am using MS Access.  I wrote a query just like this and although it works, it takes 10-15 min to run.  I had read some where that using JOINs would speed it up significantly.  Which, is the reason for my question.